# Roll view by 90 degree angle

Tags: 3d-view

How do I rotate my view by a 90 degree angle?
Regardless of how I set up these hotkeys, they roll the view at different angles than what is specified.
These commands should rotate the view by 90 degrees in orthographic view, so the North rolls to the East or West orientation for each respective hotkey.

[image: These commands should rotate the view by 90 degrees in orthographic view, so the North rolls to the East or West orientation for each respective hotkey.]

Comment: I think values are in radians.Try to enter "pi/2" instead of "90".

Comment: That doesn't work either, I'd like to single press the button, but I still have to press it 4 times. I suspect these being bugged, since none of the values affect the behaviour.

Comment: ok... use pi/2 and indicate "Roll angle" for roll angle source (not right or left)

Answer (score 4):

This setting should do:

[image]

So "pi/2" or "-pi/2" for the roll. And "Roll angle" for the roll angle source.

Comment: That's it, thanks!